# Can I ask questions about unicycles here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I am considering a unicycle, and I would like to know whether I could ask that on this SE.

Comment: As long as you don't include juggling - that would be grounds for immediate closure. NOTE: there is already a Unicycle tag with 6 questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I am concerned, a unicycle is half a bicycle. It ought to be worth half a question. As long as your question is cycling related or bike mechanics/riding relevant, I say yes. Start asking about circus tents* or non-cycling related material, and I will reserve the right to withdraw that vote.

**this is an attempt at humor. No offense is intended.*

Comment: Your 'attempt at humour' wasn't funny. Nonetheless I'm not offended. This is an attempt at humour. In NASCAR, they expect us to believe that they exercise 'safety first' How can we believe that if they don't even have child door locks or baby seat anchors? That's an attempt at humour

Comment: My attempts at humor never are. :)

Comment: Was mine funny?

Comment: I don't have the necessary expertise to judge it.

Comment: Now *that's* funny LOL

Comment: Ignoring the humor part, I agree. If it's got one or more bicycle-type wheels, some kind of pedals and otherwise basically use the same parts as a bicycle, it's on-topic here. No need to go counting the wheels to decide if it's on-topic.

Comment: I think it's OK as long as you have 2 unicycles.

Comment: [This is not a joke](http://www.google.com/imgres?hl=en&safe=off&sa=X&biw=1276&bih=683&tbm=isch&prmd=imvnsb&tbnid=JSnQjmH9HTGIaM:&imgrefurl=http://foucault.info/documents/foucault.thisIsNotaPipe.en.html&docid=QONoyD-uSwtdjM&imgurl=http://foucault.info/documents/img/notapipe/Magritte-pipe.jpg&w=510&h=364&ei=-vl3T43jLKjL0QGysqTcDQ&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=359&sig=105388809474515727904&page=1&tbnh=136&tbnw=171&start=0&ndsp=18&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0&tx=88&ty=49).

Comment: No, no, no, no. Tandems are full bikes, solos are half bikes, unicycles are a whole 'nother thing. You can't misuse terminology like that.

Comment: I thought Tandems were twice the bike. My apologies.

Comment: I'm thinking that questions about circus _tents_ should probably go to [outdoors.se].